# Why does using PageFactory initElements once in the class file gives an error

Tags: java, selenium

I want to use PageFactory initElements in the same java class and also use it only once.
It gives me an NullPointerException error. 
However if I use it in each class while entering username and password I do not get an error.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginFeature {

@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@placeholder='Username']")
WebElement objUserName;
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@placeholder='Password']")
 WebElement objPwd;
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//a[@onclick='return ValidateLogin()']")
WebElement objLoginButton;

public LoginFeature(){
    PageFactory.initElements(config.driver, this);
}
public void EnterURL(String enterURL) throws InterruptedException{
    config.driver.get(enterURL);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
public void Enterusername(String uname)
{
//PageFactory.initElements(config.driver, this); This does not give an   error. But I do not want to use it in each class separately
objUserName.sendKeys(uname);
}
public void EnterPwd(String pwd)
{
//PageFactory.initElements(config.driver, this);
objPwd.sendKeys(pwd);
}
```

Comment: which line gives NullPointerException  and what is its stacktrace?

Comment: config is not initialize.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args ) throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  LoginFeature LFeature= new LoginFeature();
  LFeature.OpenBrowser("ff32");<br\> The error is on: objUserName.sendKeys(uname);

Answer (score 0):

```
@FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@placeholder='Username']")
WebElement objUserName;
```

The above code is equivalent to below code

```
WebElement objUserName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username']"));
```

Now when you initialize page using object of `LoginFeature` class

```
PageFactory.initElements(config.driver, this);
```

and if your `driver` is not initialized then anything you access using `driver` will throw `NullPointerException`. e.g. your first page object is initialized and as soon as you use it exception happens.

Try initializing browser like this

```
public class LoginFeature {

public LoginFeature(){
    initializeDriver();
    PageFactory.initElements(config.driver, this);
}

public void initializeDriver(){
 config.driver=new ChromeDriver; 
}
  }
```